# iOS Charts Github :: Spacing

Tags: ios-charts

I'm using [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to build a line chart and have been customizing it's design. However I'm having some issues with changing some settings/designs right now. [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0Afa.png) what it currently looks like.

I can't seem to add vertical spacing between the legend and the graphs x axis labels. They are too close together.

```
let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom // Emphasis
xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .regular)
xAxis.axisLineWidth = 1
xAxis.axisMinimum = 239
xAxis.axisMaximum = 249
//xAxis.yOffset = 15 // ONLY ADDS TOP SPACE   
    
// Legend
chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false // remove from the right side
chartView.legend.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .regular)
chartView.legend.yEntrySpace = 10
chartView.legend.formSize = 10
chartView.legend.yOffset = 10 // ONLY ADDS BOTTOM SPACE
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `verticalAlignment` to `VerticalAlignment.top` (it is `VerticalAlignment.bottom` by default) should use the `yOffset` as the top space.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this parameter:

```
chartView.legend.yOffset
```

Comment: That just adds space between the bottom of legend and the bounds of the chart. Not adding space above the legend.